# bootstrap tooltip displays text and fades away properly, but is not located in a tooltip above the icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I am having trouble with my tooltip, in that it displays the text to the left and fades away on mouse over, but does not properly display it in a tooltip box over the icon.  I am using bootstrap.  A part of me thinks it could be based on something like jquery ui and jquery not working well together - would be happy to add my application.js if needed.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is how I believe the code should look on mouseover:
[image: Right Image]

Here is how it actually looks - additionally you can see the tooltip display "followers" to the left and not in a tooltip over the icon.  It changes the title to title aria-describeby "ui-tooltip-34"

[image: Wrong Image]

Here is the html for the code

```
  <li class="action-nav-button">
    <a href="#" class="tip" title="New Project" >
      <i class="icon-file-alt"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the jquery for the tooltip

```
  #tooltips
  $('.tip, [rel=tooltip]').tooltip(gravity: 'n', fade: true, html:true)
```

Here is a part of the sass

```
.action-nav-normal {
  .badge, .label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    right: 3px;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    display: block;
    @include box-shadow(none);
  }

  .triangle-button {
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    pointer-events: none;

    i {
      right: 4px;
      top: 3px;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not a real answer, but I've found Bootstrap tooltip to be pretty "dumb". I'd suggest that you take a look at qTip2, which works pretty well with Bootstrap and provides you with much more options on how to tell your tooltip where to appear, when to appear, when to disappear and how to reposition itself. http://qtip2.com/

Comment: The conflict is probably between jQuery UI and Boostrap's javascript, you may want to customize one of the libraries to remove its tooltip plugin

Answer (score 0):

Although I still need to do some more research on this I believe that this is stemming from the gem ActiveAdmin automatically including Jquery libraries.

I will post a further solution once resolved.